# Primefaces datatable issue - Persist Filter,Sort order and pagination

Tags: primefaces, datatable

We are developing an application using JSF2 with Primefaces version5.2.5

WE are using primefaces datatable in multiple places in our application. For each row in the datatable, we have an edit button and clicking on the button redirect to the "edit page", once the user saves the data in the edit page again it redirects to the main page( datatable page). We are facing couple of issues when using the datatable.

1) If the user sorts the record based on some column,going to edit page,saving the data and redirecting to the mainpage, sorting order is not maintained in the datatable when the page is getting reloaded

2) Similarly if i edit some record from second page in datatable, and after edit, its going to first page.

3) If the user applies some column filtering and editing some filtered record and when redirect to main page its not retaining the filter value, filter values are getting cleared.

Note: We are using GroupConversationScoped for the bean and we are not using ajax call for update.